# How do I work around closures causing error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime

Tags: rust

I have this "simplified" code to demonstrate a problem I am having with a more complicated project.

I have created a closure to capture some parameters so I can invoke a small function in two places without repeating the code.  Unfortunately, lifetimes are now involved, and I am having difficulty understanding what exactly has the compiler confused:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

pub struct X<'c>
{
    maybe_file: Option<Box<dyn Write+'c>>,
}

impl<'c> X<'c>
{
    pub fn wrap<'a:'c,'b:'c> (prefix:&'a str, base: &'b mut X<'b>) ->X<'c>
    {
        return X::<'c> {
            maybe_file: Some(Box::new(X::wrapper(prefix, base))),
        }
    }
    pub fn wrapper<'a, 'b>(prefix:&'a str, base:&'b mut X<'b>) -> Wrapper<'a,'b>
    {
        Wrapper {
            prefix:prefix, base:base
        }
    }

    pub fn boop_the_snoot(&self) {}
}

//

pub struct Wrapper<'a,'b>
{
    pub prefix: &'a str,
    pub base: &'b X<'b>,
}

impl<'a,'b> Write for Wrapper<'a,'b>
{
    fn write(&mut self, buf:&[u8]) ->Result<usize, std::io::Error> { Ok(0) }
    fn flush(&mut self) ->Result<(), std::io::Error> { Ok(()) }
}


pub fn bacon(x:&mut X, scale:f32)
{

}

pub fn eggs<'c>(x:&'c mut X<'c>, scale:f32)
{
    bacon( & mut X::wrap("A:\t", x), scale);

    let f = |x:& mut X| {
        bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
    };

    f(x);

    f(x);
}
```

This gives me the following compile error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'b` due to conflicting requirements
  --> /home/thoth/src/embroidery/filler/src/lifetimes_shenanigans.rs:68:19
   |
68 |       bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
   |                   ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 67:13...
  --> /home/thoth/src/embroidery/filler/src/lifetimes_shenanigans.rs:67:13
   |
67 |       let f = |x:&mut X| {
   |  _____________^
68 | |       bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
69 | |     };
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> /home/thoth/src/embroidery/filler/src/lifetimes_shenanigans.rs:68:35
   |
68 |       bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
   |                                   ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 67:13...
  --> /home/thoth/src/embroidery/filler/src/lifetimes_shenanigans.rs:67:13
   |
67 |       let f = |x:&mut X| {
   |  _____________^
68 | |       bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
69 | |     };
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
           expected &mut lifetimes_shenanigans::X<'_>
              found &mut lifetimes_shenanigans::X<'_>
```

What sort of lifetime crimes is this logic protecting me from?
What should I add to this code to enable the rust compiler to understand the lifetimes of the various objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but I think if you try to explicitly specify the relation between the lifetimes in your closure (e.g. `|x: &'d mut X<'e>|`) and the lifetime `'c` from eggs, you might get more helpful error messages?

Comment: for instance it compiles if the lifetimes for the input to the closure are tied to `'c`. [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e001465257bf84aaa4da7ca06a5b7fa)

Comment: In general, with lifetimes, less is more. Pay attention to the lifetimes that you actually need to be the same. e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2960108ebd48136d641d17d14258a615

Comment: Well, some of the lifetimes can be removed from the example because it is simplified.  I could add a couple of dozen more lines to make the motivation for the lifetimes a little clearer.  Maybe I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code to compile by replacing the declarations of the form `&'b mut X<'b>` with `&'z mut X<'b>` , basically decoupling the lifetime of the reference from the lifetime of the field inside X.

Another important change was to remove all lifetimes from the `eggs()` function.  This actually raises its own question:  Is it possible to explcitly declare the lifetimes in the eggs function and still get it to compile?  I have made a few clumsy attempts and ended up with `[E0502]: cannot borrow`*x`as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable` which confirms there are subtleties I do not yet understand.

The patch looks like this:

```rust
@@ -7,13 +7,13 @@

 impl<'c> X<'c>
 {
-    pub fn wrap<'a:'c,'b:'c> (prefix:&'a str, base: &'b mut X<'b>) ->X<'c>
+    pub fn wrap<'a:'c,'b:'c,'z:'c> (prefix:&'a str, base: &'z mut X<'b>) ->X<'c>
     {
         return X::<'c> {
             maybe_file: Some(Box::new(X::wrapper(prefix, base))),
         }
     }
-    pub fn wrapper<'a, 'b>(prefix:&'a str, base:&'b mut X<'b>) -> Wrapper<'a,'b>
+    pub fn wrapper<'a, 'b, 'z>(prefix:&'a str, base:&'z mut X<'b>) -> Wrapper<'a,'b, 'z>
     {
         Wrapper {
             prefix:prefix, base:base
@@ -25,13 +25,13 @@

 //

-pub struct Wrapper<'a,'b>
+pub struct Wrapper<'a,'b, 'z>
 {
     pub prefix: &'a str,
-    pub base: &'b X<'b>,
+    pub base: &'z X<'b>,
 }

-impl<'a,'b> Write for Wrapper<'a,'b>
+impl<'a,'b,'z> Write for Wrapper<'a,'b,'z>
 {
     fn write(&mut self, buf:&[u8]) ->Result<usize, std::io::Error> { Ok(0) }
     fn flush(&mut self) ->Result<(), std::io::Error> { Ok(()) }
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@

 }

-pub fn eggs<'c>(x:&'c mut X<'c>, scale:f32)
+pub fn eggs(x:& mut X, scale:f32)
 {
     bacon( & mut X::wrap("A:\t", x), scale);

@@ -53,5 +53,7 @@

     f(x);

+    x.boop_the_snoot();
+
     f(x);
 }
```

And the complete "fixed" source code is

```rust
use std::io::Write;

pub struct X<'c>
{
    maybe_file: Option<Box<dyn Write+'c>>,
}

impl<'c> X<'c>
{
    pub fn wrap<'a:'c,'b:'c,'z:'c> (prefix:&'a str, base: &'z mut X<'b>) ->X<'c>
    {
        return X::<'c> {
            maybe_file: Some(Box::new(X::wrapper(prefix, base))),
        }
    }
    pub fn wrapper<'a, 'b, 'z>(prefix:&'a str, base:&'z mut X<'b>) -> Wrapper<'a,'b, 'z>
    {
        Wrapper {
            prefix:prefix, base:base
        }
    }

    pub fn boop_the_snoot(&self) {}
}

//

pub struct Wrapper<'a,'b, 'z>
{
    pub prefix: &'a str,
    pub base: &'z X<'b>,
}

impl<'a,'b,'z> Write for Wrapper<'a,'b,'z>
{
    fn write(&mut self, buf:&[u8]) ->Result<usize, std::io::Error> { Ok(0) }
    fn flush(&mut self) ->Result<(), std::io::Error> { Ok(()) }
}


pub fn bacon(x:&mut X, scale:f32)
{

}

pub fn eggs(x:& mut X, scale:f32)
{
    bacon( & mut X::wrap("A:\t", x), scale);

    let f = |x:&mut X| {
        bacon(& mut X::wrap("B:\t", x), scale);
    };

    f(x);

    x.boop_the_snoot();

    f(x);
}
```

So, this is basically half an answer: the code compiles and I can continue with my project using this pattern; However it relies on the rust compiler to do some lifetime inferences while compiling eggs().  What would the code look like if we were to annotate eggs() with lifetime information that matches what the compiler infers?  The answer to that would be educational.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704612/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-elided-lifetime-parameters-from-the-rust-compiler